# on webpack external link as require([ "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="+API_KEI >> getting ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: webpack, webpack-3

how can I fix that?
on webpack external link as require([ "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="+API_KEI >>  getting ModuleNotFoundError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

manualy loader or use npm script.js